# how to solve this particular query in django queryset

Tags: python, django

```
+----+---------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
| id | user_id | foo_id    | created_at          | active    |type       |
+----+---------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
|  1 |       1 |         1 | 2011-05-10 13:12:35 |         1 | 2         |
|  7 |       5 |         2 | 2011-05-10 14:45:04 |         1 | 1         |
|  4 |       4 |         2 | 2011-05-10 13:24:45 |         1 | 2         |
|  8 |       6 |         2 | 2011-05-16 14:53:03 |         1 | 1         |
|  9 |       7 |         2 | 2011-05-16 14:55:11 |         1 | 0         |
+----+---------+-----------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+
```

This is a `UserMapper` model in django.
I want to write a query such that:

Get all the user_id whose `foo_id = 2 and type=0` and all the result of `user_id = 6;`
Say;

```
select * from table where user_id = 6 and (foo_id=2 and type=6) // Such sort of query
```

How can I do in django query set..

Comment: Your SQL doesn't match your description of what you want. Did you mean `where user_id = 6 or (food_id=2 and type=6)`?

Comment: I mean `where user_id = 6` and `(food_id=2 and type=6)`

Comment: But that's just the same as `where user_id = 6 and food_id=2 and type=6` - ie matching all three criteria, so that no rows from your example will match. Are you sure that's what you meant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean `user_id=6 and type=6 and food_id=2`, then just use:

```
UserMapper.objects.filter(user_id=6, type=6, food_id=2)
```

if you mean (`user_id=6`) `or` (`type=6 and food_id=2`), you can use the `Q` object :

```
from django.db.models import Q
UserMapper.objects.filter(Q(user_id=6) | Q(type=6, food_id=2))
```

See more about `Q` object  here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects

Answer (score 0):

```
UserMapper.objects.filter(user_id=6).filter(food_id=2).filter(type=6)
```

Answer (score 0):

`UserMapper.objects.filter(user=user).filter(foo=foo).filter(type=0)`,

where `user` is `User` object with id 6, `foo` is `Foo` with id 2 and 0 could be better with some `Type.SOMETHING` instead of just using 0.